# SQL syntax error near "where"

Tags: sql, syntax-error, where-clause

I'm a newb. This is probably an easy fix.

Query:

```
select AvgR.preavgMR - AvgR.postavgMR
from (
    ((select R.mID mID, avg(R.stars) preavgMR from Rating R group by R.mID)
    join Movie M using (mID)
    where year < 1980
    )
    join    
    ((select R.mID mID, avg(R.stars) postavgMR from Rating R group by R.mID)
    join Movie M using (mID)
    where year >= 1980
    )
) AvgR using (mID);
```

Result:

```
Query failed to execute: near "where": syntax error
```

Ideas/suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way:

```
select AvgR.preavgMR - AvgR.postavgMR
from (
    ( 
      select mID,preavgMR
      from (select R.mID mID, avg(R.stars) preavgMR from Rating R group by R.mID) T1
      join Movie M using (mID)
       where year < 1980
    )
    join    
    (
      select mID,postavgMR 
      from (select R.mID mID, avg(R.stars) postavgMR from Rating R group by R.mID) T2
    join Movie M using (mID)
    where year >= 1980
    )
) AvgR;
```

Comment: Worked - just had to move the USING clause inside that last paren. Thanks!

Comment: @user2575851 Don't forget you can also vote for the answer ;)